# Why does the main page of my website remains blank if if do document.html.style.display= ''?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have written this code to redirect if country is detected else display the page. Before redirection the main website appears so i didn't want it to show before redirection so this

```
<html style="display:none">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io/json?token=391fde43dafbc6', function (response) {

            if (response.country == "UK") {
                window.location.href = "http://www.secondwebsite.com.pk/";
            } else {
                document.body.style.display='';
            }
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

I could do this with body tag but my code is in layout file and it only has html tag. So it's not working. It redirects else the page remains white blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now check Bro I have use only html tag
Also add jquery file in your code...!

```html
<html style="display:none">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io/json?token=391fde43dafbc6', function (response) {

            if (response.country == "UK") {
                window.location.href = "http://www.secondwebsite.com.pk/";
            } else {
                $('html').css('display','block');
            }
    });
    </script>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>Its Working Now...</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Done, kindly remove your old answer.

I also I have accepted yours as an answer. cheers !